# Float elements responsively so that they move over smoothly

Tags: html, css

I am trying to float them responsively below each other irrespective of size without having empty spaces.

```
#paragraph{
 margin-top:30px;
 text-align: left;
 width:auto;
 background-color:#F5F5DC;
}
```

Here is the link to JSFiddle, to see what I mean. This is a testimonials page and I am trying to have each element float smoothly next to each other(side by side and above and below leaving no gaps except for the margin.)
I would appreciate any sort of assistance.

http://jsfiddle.net/9alamdev/zj93wn5p/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a responsive experience with fixed width elements you'll need to adjust the width of the elements using media query. An easier way would be to use percentages although you'll probably still need to use media query to get it polished. So on `.paragraph-content-testimonials` change the width to a percent. Then to remove the whitespace you'll need to remove the margins. I updated your fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/zj93wn5p/13/

Comment: That way it does become responsive but by removing the margins they stick to each other. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @UmarAftab I've updated the fiddle to use media query. play around with the values until you get it right? http://jsfiddle.net/zj93wn5p/14/

Comment: And that still does not kill the empty space between the divs floating below.So when the testimonial is small, it just floats up to fill the space.

Comment: IF you see the result of the first edit that you provided me, there is an empty space between the first one and the one below it. That was basically my question .

Comment: Unfortunately floated elements will only take up the required space which is why we have whitespace. One solution is to give each element a fixed height, or use Flexbox? https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thanks for your time, those seem to be the only 2 options. Flexbox is new to me so it might take me some time, thanks again.